# How do I stop a UIScrollView from bouncing horizontally?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UIScrollView that shows vertical data, but where the horizontal component is no wider than the screen of the iPhone. The problem is that the user is still able to drag horizontally, and basically expose blank sections of the UI. I have tried setting:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

Which helps a little, but still doesn't stop the user from being able to drag horizontally. Surely there is a way to fix this easily?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's strange, because whenever I create a scroll view with frame and content size within the bounds of the screen on either dimension, the scroll view does not scroll (or bounce) in that direction.

```
// Should scroll vertically but not horizontally
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
```

Are you sure the frame fits completely within the screen and contentSize's width is not greater than the scroll view's width?

Answer (score 22):

```
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Worked for me.

Comment: It's also disabled vertical bounces.

Answer (score 10):

The checkbox for bounce vertically in storyboard-scrollview can simply help...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

That works for me in Swift:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
scrollView.bounces = false
```

Comment: This also disables the vertical bounces.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting scrollView.bounces to NO and scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical to YES.

Comment: That's half way there, now it scrolls vertically, but never horizontally, but no longer bounces vertically...it would be nice if it could still bounce vertically, as it seems unatural to scroll without that bounce on the iPhone.

Comment: @rustyshelf I know it's a bit late, but in addition to Darron's answer, also do `scrollView. directionalLockEnabled = YES`

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not a view scrolls (and bounces) horizontally depends on three things:

- The content size
- The left and right content insets
- The width of the scroll view -

If the scroll view can fit the content size plus the insets then it doesn't scroll or bounce.

Avoid horizontal bouncing like so:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width - scrollView.contentInset.left - scrollView.contentInset.right, height);
```

I am adding this answer because the previous ones did not take contentInset into account.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the UIScrollView's contentSize is not wider than the UIScrollView itself.  In my own apps this was enough to avoid horizontal scrolling, except in cases where I got really crazy swiping in random directions (e.g., starting a scroll while the view was still decelerating).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone developing for OS X is looking here, as of OS X 10.7, the solution is to set the [horizontalScrollElasticity](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsscrollview/1403540-horizontalscrollelasticity) property to `false`/`NO` on the scroll view, like this:

Swift:

```
scrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = false
```

Objective-C:

```
scrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = NO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable horizontal bounces like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.contentSize.width) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

It resets the contentOffset.x manually and won't affect the vertical bounces. It works...

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind: *You* know there's nothing extra to see horizontally, but will your users know that? You may want a little horizontal bounce, even if there's no extra content to show horizontally. This let's the user know that their attempts to scroll horizontally are not being ignored, there's just nothing there for them to see. But, yeah, often you really don't want the bounce.

Answer (score 0):

My version for webViews, a common solution:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

[webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i just need to set this line:

`collectionView.bounces = false`