# Stop UIWebView from "bouncing" vertically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiwebview

Does anyone know how to stop a UIWebView from bouncing vertically? I mean when a user touches their iphone screen, drags their finger downwards, and the webview shows a blank spot above the web page I had loaded?

I've looked at the following possible solutions, but none of them worked for me:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/996-turn-off-scrolling-bounces-uiwebview.html

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=619534

[How do I stop a UIScrollView from bouncing horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173786/how-do-i-stop-a-uiscrollview-from-bouncing-horizontally)

Comment: I hope you have considered the usability implications of disabling that feature. It's there for a reason. That said, I'm curious, too, how you'd do that.

Comment: The way I have it embedded in my app, it appears seemlessly with some other view elements I have, and the only time it doesn't appear so is when the bounce happens.... Definitely a good point though!

Answer (score 430, accepted):

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
  if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
    ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

...seems to work fine.

It'll be accepted to App Store as well.

**Update**: in iOS 5.x+ there's an easier way - `UIWebView` has `scrollView` property, so your code can look like this:

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Same goes for `WKWebView`.

Comment: It works. No subclassing required and if Apple ever change the UIWebView hierarchy, it shouldn't crash.

Comment: This fix seems to only work in my OS 4.1 Simulator, not on my OS 3.1.3 iPhone.  Does anybody know if this fix only works on particular OS versions?

Comment: @MirukRusin - How can you guarantee that this app will be accepted based on three lines of code? :P

Comment: @Mirek - You missed my point. How do you know that nothing else in the app will get it rejected?

Comment: :D hehehe.. i guarantee your app will not be rejected if you remember to pass along those three little lines of code..

Comment: This worked fine for me. For convenience, I added a category to `UIWebView` so I could call `[webView setBounces:NO]` anywhere I wanted to.

Comment: webView.scrollView.bounces = NO; seems to work in iOS 4.3 as well

Comment: why have you labelled the dot notation as old? Isn't the property dot notation relatively new?

Comment: If you prefer to use bracket syntax... `[self.webView.scrollView setBounces:NO];`

Comment: This works in swift as well, but I had to do 
webView?.scrollView.bounces = false;

Comment: @MirukRusin it works but is it possible to bounce only top?

Answer (score 46):

I was looking at a project that makes it easy to create web apps as full fledged installable applications on the iPhone called [QuickConnect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickconnect/), and found a solution that works, if you don't want your screen to be scrollable at all, which in my case I didn't.

In the above mentioned project/blog post, they mention a javascript function you can add to turn off the bouncing, which essentially boils down to this:

```
    document.ontouchmove = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

If you want to see more about how they implement it, simply download QuickConnect and check it out.... But basically all it does is call that javascript on page load... I tried just putting it in the head of my document, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: This answer is the correct way to stop the vertical scrolling of the content within a UIWebView.

Comment: You could have given the whole answer, firstly I don't want to download a whole scource code of another app, and I can't even find it. Your answer relies on another website being the same as when you answered.

Comment: This answer & the accepted answer above seem to be required at times. In my case, I found that if the web view was not loaded yet, the bounciness would be there until the JS above was actually loaded into the system. So the answer seems to be that this and the accepted answer above are both, at times, required.

Comment: as Jessedc said, this will stop vertical scrolling, not only bouncing. that means if you have div or so that requires scrolling, it will not scroll.

Answer (score 18):

Well all I did to accomplish this is :

```
UIView *firstView = [webView.subviews firstObject];

if ([firstView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

    UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView*)firstView;
   [scroll setScrollEnabled:NO];  //to stop scrolling completely
   [scroll setBounces:NO]; //to stop bouncing 

}
```

Works fine for me... 
Also, the ticked answer for this question is one that Apple will reject if you use it in
your iphone app.

Comment: This is the best and most simplest way. This should be the accepted answer! +1

Comment: Dont do that - my app got rejected for using the first line. Wasted so much time for me. i used [[webView.subviews lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO]; and apple said it was a private API and hence rejected  it; am about to resubmit now but used "userInteractionEnabled:NO" since i dont need any active links in the app.

Comment: UIWebView inherits from UIView. UIView has property subviews. What is private here? All of this you can find on developer.apple.com

Comment: I have something like 4 apps on the appstore using this. You app was clearly rejected for another reason. this is not a private API.

Comment: This is really not a good idea. You're relying on the fact that the `UIScrollView` is the first subview of `UIWebView` which may well be the case for now but this could easily change in future (even minor) updates to iOS or particular configurations. You should really do a `for` iteration over `subviews` to actually find the `UIScrollView` (it really isn't that much work and at least you are guaranteed to get a `UIScrollView` and not crash your program...

Comment: @Jonathan Ellis : I updated my code to check that the first subview is a scroll view before making calls on it. It is true that this still assumes the first subview is a scrollview but it is highly unlikely that this would change and if it does the code will not crash now. (A for loop seems overkill and there may be other scrollviews to look out for in the future so I think it carries a risk as well)

Answer (score 17):

In the iOS 5 SDK you can access the scroll view associated with a web view directly rather than iterating through its subviews.

So to disable 'bouncing' in the scroll view you can use:

```
myWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

See the [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW35).

(However if you need to support versions of the SDK before 5.0, you should follow [Mirek Rusin's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3324886/387310).)

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3

```
webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

Answer (score 9):

Warning.  I used setAllowsRubberBanding: in my app, and Apple rejected it, stating that non-public API functions are not allowed (cite: 3.3.1)

Answer (score 4):

In Swift to disable bounces

```
webViewObj.scrollView.bounces = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Brad's method worked for me. If you use it you might want to make it a little safer.

```
id scrollView = [yourWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
if( [scrollView respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsRubberBanding:)] )
{
    [scrollView performSelector:@selector(setAllowsRubberBanding:) withObject:NO];
}
```

If apple changes something then the bounce will come back - but at least your app won't crash.

Answer (score 3):

On iOS5 only if you plan to let the users zoom the webview contents (e.i.: double tap) the bounce setting isn't enough. You need to set also alwaysBounceHorizontal and alwaysBounceVertical properties to NO, else when they zoom-out (another double tap...) to default it will bounce again.

Answer (score 2):

I traversed the collection of UIWebView's subviews and set their backgrounds to [UIColor blackColor], the same color as the webpage background. The view will still bounce but it will not show that ugly dark grey background.

Comment: Actually it's a pretty bad one, because if Apple ever changes the internals of UIWebView, this hack could break.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the UIWebView has a UIScrollView. You can use documented APIs for this, but bouncing is set for both directions, not individually. This is in the API docs.
UIScrollView has a bounce property, so something like this works (don't know if there's more than one scrollview):

```
NSArray *subviews = myWebView.subviews;
NSObject *obj = nil;
int i = 0;
for (; i < subviews.count ; i++)
{
    obj = [subviews objectAtIndex:i];

    if([[obj class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] == YES)
    {
        ((UIScrollView*)obj).bounces = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was annoyed to find out that UIWebView is not a scroll view, so I made a custom subclass to get at the web view's scroll view. This suclass contains a scroll view so you can customize the behavior of your web view. The punchlines of this class are:

```
@class CustomWebView : UIWebview
...

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
// WebViews are subclass of NSObject and not UIScrollView and therefore don't allow customization.
// However, a UIWebView is a UIScrollViewDelegate, so it must CONTAIN a ScrollView somewhere.
// To use a web view like a scroll view, let's traverse the view hierarchy to find the scroll view inside the web view.
for (UIView* v in self.subviews){
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        _scrollView = (UIScrollView*)v; 
        break;
    }
}
return self;
```

}

Then, when you create a custom web view, you can disable bouncing with:

```
customWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO; //(or customWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertically = NO)
```

This is a great general purpose way to make a web view with customizable scrolling behavior. There are just a few things to watch out for:

- as with any view, you'll also need to override -(id)initWithCoder: if you use it in Interface Builder
- when you initially create a web view, its content size is always the same as the size of the view's frame. After you scroll the web, the content size represents the size of the actual web contents inside the view. To get around this, I did something hacky - calling -setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,1)animated:YES to force an unnoticeable change that will set the proper content size of the web view.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this searching for an answer and I eventually just lucked on an answer of my own by messing about. I did

```
[[webview scrollView] setBounces:NO];
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, and beautifully too (I am using phonegap with webView)

```
[[webView.webView scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

or

```
[[webView scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two newer potential solutions. Apparently, you can use jqtouch or pastrykit to disable scrolling. However, I haven't got these to work. You might be more competent.

[turning off vertical scrolling](http://blog.jqtouch.com/post/285889760/turning-off-vertical-scrolling)

[digging into pastrykit](http://waynepan.com/2009/12/16/digging-into-pastrykit)

Answer (score 1):

[fixed positioning on mobile safari](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/)

This link helped me lot.....Its easy.. There is a demo..

Answer (score 1):

I tried a slightly different approach to prevent **UIWebView** objects from scrolling and bouncing: adding a gesture recognizer to override other gestures.

It seems, **UIWebView** or its scroller subview uses its own pan gesture recognizer to detect user scrolling. But according to Apple's documentation there is a legitimate way of overriding one gesture recognizer with another. **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** protocol has a method **gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:** - which allows to control the behavior of any colliding gesture recognizers.

So, what I did was

in the view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
// Install a pan gesture recognizer                                                                                        // We ignore all the touches except the first and try to prevent other pan gestures                                                     
// by registering this object as the recognizer's delegate                                                                                        
UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer;                                                                                                               
recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];                                                   
recognizer.delegate = self;                                                                                                                       
recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;                                                                                                            
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];                                                                                                          
self.panGestureFixer = recognizer;                                                                                                                  
[recognizer release];
```

then, the gesture override method:

```
// Control gestures precedence                                                                                                                            
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer                                                                                        
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                         
        // Prevent all panning gestures (which do nothing but scroll webViews, something we want to disable in                                          
        // the most painless way)                                                                                                                         
        if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])                                                                        
        {
            // Just disable every other pan gesture recognizer right away                                                                             
            otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = FALSE;
        }                                                                                                                                                  
        return NO;                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Of course, this delegate method can me more complex in a real application - we may disable other recognizers selectively, analyzing **otherGestureRecognizer.view** and making decision based on what view it is.

And, finally, for the sake of completeness, the method we registered as a pan handler:

```
- (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
    // do nothing as of yet
}
```

it can be empty if all we want is to cancel web views' scrolling and bouncing, or it can contain our own code to implement the kind of pan motions and animations we really want...

So far I'm just experimenting with all this stuff, and it seems to be working more or less as I want it. I haven't tried to submit any apps to iStore yet, though. But I believe I haven't used anything undocumented so far... If anyone finds it otherwise, please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

(Xcode 5 iOS 7 SDK example) Here is a Universal App example using the scrollview setBounces  function. It is an open source project / example located here: [Link to SimpleWebView (Project Zip and Source Code Example)](https://github.com/matthewferguson/SimpleWebView.git)

Answer (score 0):

One of the subviews of `UIWebView` should be a `UIScrollView`. Set its `scrollEnabled` property to `NO` and the web view will have scrolling disabled entirely.

Note: this is technically using a private API and thus your app could be rejected or crash in future OS releases. Use `@try` and `respondsToSelector`

Comment: I tried this out, and it faults when I try it... Strangely, i can access and set scrollView.bounces (with no effect), but when I try and set scrollEnabled, it faults...

Comment: I believe the subview is called UIScroller, not UIScrollView.

UIScroller is an undocumented and unsupported class that shares a lot in common with UIScrollView, but you can't depend on everything working the same way and not changing in future OS versions.

Comment: I did this on an iPad (not iPhone) app running iOS 3.2, and was able to get a UIScrollView out of my UIWebView. I successfully customized this view to change more than just its bouncing behavior so I can testify to this working on iPad.

My app did not go through the app store, but I don't think there will be a problem with undocumented API's here. The clever part for this solution is that you're just traversing a UIView hierarchy and using a UIScrollView - both of which are perfectly kosher.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `bounces` property of `UIScrollView`. Quoth the Apple docs:

> If the value of the property is `YES` (the default), the scroll view bounces when it encounters a boundary of the content. Bouncing visually indicates that scrolling has reached an edge of the content. If the value is `NO`, scrolling stops immediately at the content boundary without bouncing.

Make sure you're using the right `UIScrollView`. I'm not sure what the hierarchy looks like for a `UIWebView`, but the scroll view could be a parent, not a child, of the `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

To disable `UIWebView` scrolling you could use the following line of code:

```
[ObjWebview setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
```

In this example, `ObjWebview` is of type `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
webView.scrollView.bounces=NO;