# How to turn off the bounce in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop UIWebView from “bouncing” vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically)

can you just help me turning off the bounce in the UIWebView. Because when we over scroll it it displays the unnecessary space with the grayish back ground.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
for (id subview in YourWebView.subviews){
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
}
```