# How to disable horizontal scroll in uiwebview?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am using uiwebview in my code and implemented swipe function on uiwebview. For swipe function i have set YES for scaleToFir property for webview, when we give, scaleToFit=YES, content get shrinked. But for my case both needed. swipe aswell as content should not shrink. But disable horizontal bar is fine. can you please help me out?

Srini

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to disable UIWebview horizontal scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397699/how-to-disable-uiwebview-horizontal-scrolling) and [how to disable horizontal scroll for a uiwebview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758678/how-to-disable-horizontal-scroll-for-a-uiwebview).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIScrollView *scroll in [webview subviews]) {
    // Make sure it really is a scroll view and reset the zoom scale.
    if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:)]){
        scroll.bounces=FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
NSLog(@"loaded");
[webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];
}
```