# Stop webview from "Bouncing" (Monotouch / C#)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I'm using Monotouch to develop an iPhone application.
I'm aware there are answers out there for this question already for Objective-C. For example:

[Stop UIWebView from bouncing vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically)

This answer is ideal. I figured I could just take it, and turn it into C# and it'll be fine.

The Objective-C code is:

```
  for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
      ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

I couldn't find anything similar to `isSubclassOfClass:` in C# and after a little experimenting, I found my webView only contained one subview, which was a scrollview. So I tried the following C# code:

```
foreach (var view in webView.Subviews)
{
   webView.Subviews[0].Bounces = false;
}
```

This should've worked except the returned type of `webView.Subviews[0]` was type `UIView` not `UIScrollView` - this meant the compiler complains the `UIView` doesn't have a property "bounces" (which is correct.)

So my question is, what would be the appropriate way of doing this? Is there a way I can get the UIScrollView instance from the subviews? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luke,

If you're wanting to follow the same example as the Obj-C then you will want to do something like this;

```
foreach (var view in webView.Subviews.OfType<UIScrollView>())
{
   view.Bounces = false;
}
```

since the example above assumes that the first view in a webView is a UIScrollView, which may change in the future.

Hope this helps,

ChrisNTR

Answer (score 2):

This is a stab in the dark but:

```
((UIScrollView)webView.Subviews[0]).Bounces = false;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Truth be told, I'm kinda embarassed that I didn't think of this myself