# HTML 5 fixed screen iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, webkit

I can't seem to find the right tag.  When the screen is swiped on iPad in certain places the whole screen moves, with the "rubber band" effect I know there is a way to lock the screen, specific to HTML5 and webkit.

using `<iframe src="" width="1024" height="724" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

seems like a cheap fix, these are my headers.

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    // document.body works probably too
    document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
</script>
```

Note that this approach disables scrolling on the whole page! Sometimes this might be undesirable. If so, check out [How to Disable Rubber Band in iOS Web Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357844/how-to-disable-rubber-band-in-ios-web-apps)

Comment: I thought there might be a new webkit or html5 meta tag that does this. Will try this.

Comment: do not understand what event does, I don't think it's a reserved word. do you pass something through <body ontouchmove="blockMove(event)">

Comment: "preventDefault" cancels the default action done on the event (standard JS trick). I simplified the solution a bit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically for a related question.

Comment: I'm surprised this is not a more common fix, the problem is not addressed in any step by step tutorials nor the O'Reilly book.

Comment: This is a fairly common trick in JS coding. Note that it disables two finger "scrolling" on elements with overflow. I doubt many people use that though gives it's quite an obscure feature.

Comment: And if you use swipe gestures on the site? What then, you ignore them now.

Comment: @trgraglia Good point. Perhaps there's a better solution around these days. Any ideas?

Comment: @bebraw Haven't looked into it. There should be an easy solution but I have said that before and spent hours. Sorry, no help here.

Comment: This is not a good solution because it disables all scrolling on the page.  We obviously need to be able to scroll listviews, etc. but do not want the rubber banding effect.

Comment: @ObiWan Valid point! Looks like you need to do some magic to ignore certain child elements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357844/how-to-disable-rubber-band-in-ios-web-apps .

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people don't read the comments on the answer, here is a solution I found when investigating to answers @bebraw 's comment:

[How to disable rubber band in iOS web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357844/how-to-disable-rubber-band-in-ios-web-apps)

It is a lot of work for something so small but allows a granular approach on what get the scroll and what doesn't.