# How to disable vertical scroll while enable swipeleft and swiperight event using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe, vertical-scrolling

I have a html jquery mobile multi-page and using swipeleft and swiperight events to flip pages.
it works great.

Now I wanna disable the vertical scroll.

From solution I found in stackoverflow, it suggest to use the following

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-content', 'touchmove', false);​
```

but in this case, the original swipeleft and swiperight events are disabled too.

Is there a way that I can disable the vertical scroll while keeping the swipeleft and swiperight events?

Comment: if you are disabling vertical scroll; arent your pages already smaller than the viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following to your

```
<script>
    function BlockMove(event) {
      // Tell Safari not to move the window.
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    </script>
```

and add this to your body tag

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);" ontouchmove="BlockMove(event);">
```

This will disable the page scrolling allowing you to swipe

Comment: Hi Donald,

it works. Thanks.

But may I ask what is the purpose of setting the timeout function?
And now every time after page flip, it take a while for the content to get focus. i.e. texts in pages are a bit blur and become clear within 1 seconds.

Comment: Here is another script which is really cool and allows for a lot of options... no more than 50 lines of JS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357844/how-to-disable-rubber-band-in-ios-web-apps