# Disable Scrolling Web Page iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I've seen a lot of solutions involving stopping all touchmove events. However this won't work for me, as my app involves a drawing canvas. Is there a way to ensure that users can't scroll, while preserving other touchevents?
--Ashley

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` in your drawing handlers, or in a handler attached further up the DOM tree. This just prevents the default behaviour of the `touchmove` which is to scroll.

```
$('body, html').on('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You'll still be able to handle `touchmove` events on your drawing canvas.

Another option would be to set `overflow:hidden` in your CSS - but this depends on the size of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look to this answer..
[Prevent touchmove default on parent but not child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486195/prevent-touchmove-default-on-parent-but-not-child)

Put your canvas in a container and stop scrolling on the parent.

```
$('body').delegate('#fix','touchmove',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

}).delegate('.scroll','touchmove',function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();

});
```