# Disabling scrolling on iPad

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, overflow, scalable

I've made a website responsive for iPad. I used "overflow:hiddden" and "user-scalable=no". On Android tablets, users can't scroll as I want to. But in iPad, those little anarchists can scroll (vertical and horizontal) and that screws up my website. How can I block to scroll on iPad?

Comment: Check out the answers to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512458/disable-scrolling-web-page-ipad?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I hope it helps