# Prevent body from scrolling but not any parent div on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touch

I want my `body` not to scroll if `'not-scroll'` class is appended on it, otherwise it should work normally.

I have been searching for this problem for 2 days, but can't find any solution working for me.

What I want is to add a `class` to `body`, and it should not scroll if any one try to scroll on it. But every other `element` should scroll, if scrolling is possible in them. 
I have already read so many stackoverflow answers, but nothing is workable for me. I have checked out, [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened),[solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling),[solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868996/prevent-body-element-from-scrolling-on-touch-devices),[solution 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486195/prevent-touchmove-default-on-parent-but-not-child) and many others..

PS: Actually, I am implementing [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) in my application, which opens a model screen on the `body`, now if user tries to scroll on the model, `body` behind the model view scrolls. I want to prevent this.

I have tried this.

```
$(document).on('touchmove',function(event) {
     if($('body').hasClass('no-scroll')) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

but it also prevents scrolling inside model view. Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Scenario is like shown in picture, captured form iPad mini[image: Image:]

Comment: You can't prevent scrolling, but you can remove the overflow when the modal is visible.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by adeneo, set overflow to hidden on body on activating the modal.

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');  //set overflow hidden
```

And when the dialog box closes, add overflow as auto

**EDIT:** Also, try preventing scroll on overlay ('.fancybox-overlay') rather than body

**EDIT-2:** Try to include whole of your content inside a wrapper and scroll that instead of the body.(refer [THIS](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/02/prevent-page-behind-jquery-ui-dialog-from-scrolling/)).

Comment: This is also preventing scrolling inside any child div of model.

Comment: @hemkaran_raghav now check the solution

Comment: I have also tried that, but it arises 2 problems for me, first is, if I will open model after scrolling down the body, it will scroll the body to top. and second is the bouncing effect in iOS.

Comment: @hemkaran_raghav try preventing scroll on overlay ('.fancybox-overlay')

Answer (score 0):

To prevent scrolling you can specify

```
body{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

To allow scrolling to any other div inside body

```
div{
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

You can use overflow-y property for vertical , overflow-x property for horizontal or overflow property for both

Comment: Thanx for the answer. But I cant update my body to have 'overflow:hidden' or 'height:100%'.

Comment: Does this actually work on iOS7? For me not. Elastic body scrolling is still enabled. And switching it off by document.body.addEventListener( 'touchmove', function(event) {event.preventDefault();}, false ) disables all elements from being scrollable.