# How to configure BXSlider to scroll the contents of a <div> vertically within a horizontal slider on mobile?

Tags: css, touch, overflow, bxslider

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch!important;
```

...doesn't seem to work, what else needs configuring?

**More detail:** I'm working with BXSlider and it's scrolling horizontally on mobile perfectly well. What I'd like to achieve is to scroll the overflow content within each slide on touch enabled devices (this works on desktop browsers btw):

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li>
    <div id="scrolling-vertical" style="overflow: scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch!important;">
        ... content that should scroll ...
    </div>
</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    touchEnabled:true,  // Debugging purposes

    preventDefaultSwipeX:true, // Attempt to reintroduce vertical scrolling for slide content
    preventDefaultSwipeY:false, // Horitontal scrolling not required

    swipeThreshold:128, // Debugging purposes
    oneToOneTouch:false // Debugging purposes
});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't there a parameter that drives it to be a vertical slider?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want that. I'd like the contents of the <div> to scroll vertically (like a normal page), but nest these small pages inside the BXslider.

I believe what your suggesting is the whole slider to be vertical. That is "vertical mode": http://bxslider.com/docs/jquery.bxslider.html

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Without having an explicit example to test, I would say that you are on the right path. If you set up a fiddle, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Chad. I found the problem once I'd isolated it satisfactorily. To correct the error, I used this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488447/iphone-web-app-stop-body-scrolling

However, it's not got great scrolling support everywhere, so I'll have to look into a better solution.

Comment: I can confirm BounceFix.js is a light weight solution to correcting problematic circumstances where `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` isn't enough.

It's a simple to addition to any class in your layout: http://jaridmargolin.github.io/bouncefix.js/

Comment: I'd like to explore the problem without an extra library. Would you mind setting up a fiddle?