# How to disable rubber band effect iOS?

Tags: css

I am trying to disable the rubber band effect on iOS when I make use of the  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

Does anyone know how to fix the rubber band in combination with the  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` snippet?

Demo code:
http://codepen.io/Caspert/pen/BopMrj

Look out for some answer.
Casper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone Web App - Stop body scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488447/iphone-web-app-stop-body-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found was to make the body position:fixed. Like so:

```
body
{
   position:fixed;
}
```

Any divs inside the body can then be made to scroll, by setting a height on them and using overflow:auto.

Comment: Does not seem to do anything at the moment. Still rubber banding.

Answer (score 0):

set bounces={false} in scrollview