# Dojo app header and footer are not fixed positioned in Windows and iPhone

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-8, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing hybrid app using IBM MobileFirst 7.0 and dojox 1.8 as scripting language.

i am facing problem with UI Header and Footer which are not fixed in windows and iphone but the same code is working fine with Android.

i.e, For heading, we used  tag and gave `data-dojo-props:"fixed:top"` for heading.
For footer, we used  tag and gave `data-dojo-props:"fixed:bottom"` for footer.

please can any suggest for solution?

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="Login_en_View_Id"
    data-dojo-props="selected:false">

    <h1 class="test" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props="fixed:'top'"></h1>

    <div class="margin">

        <label >Text:</label> <input class="clearFields"
            data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" >

        <label>Code</label> <input class="clearFields"
            data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox">


        <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" class="englishFont">Login</button> 

        <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" class="englishFont">REGISTER</button>


    </div>

    <h2  class="test1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props="fixed:'bottom'"></h2>
</div>
```

Css code:

```
    .test{  
        height: 42px;
        display: table;
        line-height: 0px;
    }
   .test1{
        height: 44px;
   }
```

Comment: This is a programming website. Provide your implementation so that it could be recreated and debugged. Also confirm if you are referring to Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8.

Comment: We are referring for windows phone 8 and iphone

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what do you mean by "not fixed positioned".
I've used your code and both the header and the footer are indeed *fixed positioned* to the top and bottom.

What I think you may be referring to is that you are able to scroll the page and the header/footer is moving with you (note, though, that it is still *fixed* at the "top/bottom").

To "fix" this you can put the following at the beginning of the `wlCommonInit()` function:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

That is very rudimentary, but works. There will be no more scrolling.
You can find additional solutions here: [iPhone Web App - Stop body scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488447/iphone-web-app-stop-body-scrolling)