# Avoid uiwebview so much vertical scrolling

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I want to avoid this on a UIWebView:

[image]

As you can see html page ends and UIWebView continues scrolling page to top. I've marked page ends with a red ellipse.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: And this question is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using iOS5?  If so then:

```
webView.scrollview.bounces = NO;
```

If you're not using iOS5, then you can search through the webView's subviews for the UIScrollView (isKindOfClass) and then set the bounces property.