# iOS scrollview.bounces make app crash on iOS 4.x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

scrollView.bounces works properly on iOS 5 but when executed on iOS 4, sigabrt error is shown. How to set it working for both os? Thank you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self.webView1 setDelegate:self];

    self.webView1.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.webViewB.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self loadIt];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the setting the `bounces` property of the `scrollView` but rather trying to access the `scrollView` property of the `webView1` and `webViewB` objects. Before iOS 5.0 this property was not public so you cannot access it like that.

You would have to go trough all the suviews of the `webView1` and `webViewB` and find the one that's a `UIScrollView` and than set it's `bouncing` property. You can do that like this:

```
if ([self.webView1 respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
    self.webView1.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.webViewB.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
else {
    for (UIView *subview in self.webView1.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            scrollView.bounces = NO;
        }
    }

    for (UIView *subview in self.webViewB.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            scrollView.bounces = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I'd recommend putting this code into a category on `UIWebView` so you don't have to repeat it all through your apps :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because web views in iOS 4 don't have a scrollView property - I think that arrived in iOS 5 :)

Look at the answer from [Stop UIWebView from "bouncing" vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically) to fix it.