# disable horizontal scroll view in uiwebview

Tags: objective-c

I have a view whose size is 650, I added a `UIWebView` to this view. When I load information in to `WebView`, the scroll horizontal is working. I want to disable horizontal scroll in `WebView`.

Can the content fit with my view?

Comment: Try checking its property scale page to fit ,from xib .

Comment: [Please check this it may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

[webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below meta to html head, if you are able to modify the html.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```