# WKWebView.scrollView.bounces = false is Not working

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, bounce

I click the button to go to another Webview. However, I removed the `bounce` from the moved Webview, but it does not work.

### First WKWebView

```swift
    var openSecondScreen : SecondWebViewController!
    var preloadCheck = false
   ...
    func openSecondScreen(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        openSecondScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondWebViewController") as! SecondWebViewController
        openSecondScreen.delegate = self
        openSecondScreen.loadViewIfNeeded()
        openSecondScreen.secondWKWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        preloadCheck = true
    }
....
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if preloadCheck {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openSecondScreen, animated: true)
            preloadCheck = false
        }
    }
```

### Second WKWebView

```swift
@IBOutlet var secondWKWebView: WKWebView!
...
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    secondWKWebView.uiDelegate = self
    secondWKWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    secondWKWebView.scrollView.delegate = self
    ...
}

extension SecondWebViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollViewDidScroll")
        scrollView.bounces = false
    }
}
```

Scroll does not display the log. Therefore, the function does not work either.

### Editing: I don't think I wrote this down in advance. I'm even setting it up in advance.But it didn't work

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        secondWKWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope this helps:
[Remove vertical bounce on webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically)

Comment: @SchaheerSaleem Look at the revised question.

Comment: Try moving the code from loadView to viewDidLoad for the secondViewController and remove these lines from firstViewController

openSecondScreen.delegate = self
openSecondScreen.loadViewIfNeeded()
openSecondScreen.secondWKWebView.navigationDelegate = self

Comment: @SchaheerSaleem it same. Did not work